# Using F# in Visual Studio Community on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, f#-interactive

I use Visual Studio Code on Linux for F# programming.
Recently I installed Visual Studio Community on Windows 10 to have more math graphing features.
But i can't run .fsx scripts in the studio environment, "run debug|run" are greyed out.
Also the f# command shell is missing. 
A few years ago i used this on windows , what do i have to install?, the Microsoft Website
is not very clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as can find now:
It seems like the separate fsi.exe does not exist any more.
It looks like its all integrated in Visual Studio Code now.
Also one cant run a .fsx file directly from Visual Studio Code by double clicking, the shell have to be started first bu Ctl+Alt+F.

But then how does one run fsx scripts on Windows without VS?